# Theorems in MK would imply theorems in ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory, second-order-logic

Will theorems of MK, which has formulas which wff in ZFC also, be theorems in ZFC.

What about same for theroems of NBG for implying about theorems of ZFC?

And what will be accurate statement, if any, for saying about relationship between theorems of NBG and theorems of MK?

Comment: This is easily answered by a visit to the wikipedia page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory . MK is strictly stronger than NBG and is a proper extension of ZFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing ZFC with NBG or MK, you are asking about is (the lack of) **conservativity**. The following are well-known, and can be found at [the relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory):

- NBG is conservative over ZFC: if $\varphi$ is a sentence in the language of NBG with all quantifiers ranging over sets only which is provable from NBG, then $\varphi$ is provable in ZFC. Meanwhile, MK is not: MK proves the consistency of ZFC. (Note that this also means that there are theorems of MK which are not theorems of ZFC.)
- Actually, the previous bullet point is technically sometimes false. We have to be careful here: usually$^*$ NBG is written in the same language as ZFC, and the set/class distinction is a *definable* one (a set is a class which is an element of some class). This leads to failures of conservativity: e.g. NBG proves "$\exists x\forall y(x\not\in y)$" (that is, there is a proper class) whereas obviously ZFC proves the opposite. The "right" way to formalize class theories like NBG or MK here is via *sorts*: have a sort for sets and a sort for classes. So e.g. NBG proves $\forall x^{set}\exists y^{set}(x\in y)$, and the same sentence - when we drop the set sort, since no sorts exist in the language of ZFC - is provable in ZFC.
- If we work without sorts, then we need an appropriate *translation* from one language to another. For a sentence $\varphi$ in the language of set theory, let $\hat{\varphi}$ be the sentence gotten by inductively replacing every "$\exists x(\psi)$" and "$\forall x(\psi)$" in $\varphi$ with "$\exists x((\exists y(x\in y))\wedge\psi)$" and "$\forall x((\exists y(x\in y))\implies \psi)$" respectively where $y$ is a variable not used in $\varphi$ (this is an instance of a more general process called *relativizing the quantifiers*); then for all $\varphi$, we have ZFC proves $\varphi$ iff NBG proves $\hat{\varphi}$.

---

$^*$Historical note: actually, Bernays originally formulated NBG using sorts. Godel replaced the sorts with (equivalent) unary predicates (sorts are only meaningfully different from predicate symbols when we have infinitely many of them). The "same language" approach, as far as I know, was first used by Mendelson.

Comment: So under this translation, we can prove MK(without sorts) is conservative extension of ZF, right?

Comment: And just under translation which I said because $\exists x\forall y(x\notin y)$ is also provable in MK.

Comment: And Is defintion of conservative extension includes 'Subtheory upto isomorphism' or just subtheory?

Comment: @Sushil No. As I said above, MK proves the consistency of ZF. It's NBG which is the conservative extension. As to the definition of "conservative extension," things are awkwardly inconsistent: technically it means just a subtheory, but in an unfortunate abuse of notation it's often used in cases where there is a natural interpretation of theories under consideration.

Comment: Oh sorry. So when wiki said about NBG being conservative extension of ZF. It is taking NBG with sorts, right? Is there equivalent version of NBG without sorts. I think NBG is second order language and there is no version of first order language for it.

Comment: But if NBG second order language, how is ZF its subtheory?

Comment: @Sushil The first-order language version of NBG is just what I described in my answer: same language as ZF, all objects are classes, and proper classes are those classes which are not an element of any class. (Note that regardless of what language we use to formalize it, NBG is a first-order *theory*, that is, a theory using first-order as opposed to second-order logic - this can get a bit confusing)

Comment: @Sushil "But if NBG second order language, how is ZF its subtheory?" Technically we need another translation here: replace each variable on the ZF end with a "sets-sort" variable on the NBG end. Or, we could say that ZF *does* have a single ("sets") sort of variables, and NBG adds another sort on top of that.

Comment: Yes I am really confused when you said that 'whatever language we use to formalise, NBG is first-order'. It would then also imply that NBG can never prove its consistency. Isn't that?

Comment: @Sushil "It would then also imply that NBG can never prove its consistency." Yes, of course NBG can never prove its own consistency (assuming it is in fact consistent) since that would contradict Godel. Why do you think NBG does prove its own consistency (or do you)?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I thought that it might be. But that NBG can't prove its consistency will not directly from Godel Second Incompleteness theorem, right? (because that is only for first order languages)

Comment: @Sushil No, it does follow just from Godel. Godel's theorem(s) apply to all (appropriate) first-order theories where "first-order" here means "in first-order logic." Adding more sorts - that is, going to a two-sorted language (a much better term than "second order language") - doesn't affect things at all.

Comment: Ya I think I was right in writing previous comment which I deleted. But NBG is a special second order language. Will Godel incompleteness theorem hold for  all second order language?

Comment: or better be say 'reasonable second order language'?

Comment: @Sushil Yes, it will - like I said before, there's nothing special about two-sorted languages. (And we should really call them "two-sorted," not "second-order" - since the latter sounds like second-order *logic*, which is indeed a quite different thing from first-order logic.)