# What formula proved in MK or Godel Incompleteness theorem

Tags: logic, set-theory

As question arise from answer on discussion in this:

[Theorems in MK would imply theorems in ZFC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603291/theorems-in-mk-would-imply-theorems-in-zfc/)

'consistency of ZF can't prove consistency of MK because consistency of MK proves consistency of ZF'. Does 'MK proves Con(ZF)' where Con(ZF) is particular formula used by Godel.

As in wikipedia page:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann–Bernays–Gödel_set_theory

'NBG—and hence ZFC—can be proved consistent in MK.'

What formula MK proves for consistency of these theories.

And linking this to my another question: [Clarification about Godel Second Incompleteness theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603355/clarification-about-godel-second-incompleteness-theorem)

Does Con(ST) in second incompleteness theorem is kind of formula which had to be true if ST is consistent. i.e. (It is not obviously of type that if it is not true, then ST is not consistent)

Comment: MK builds a model of ZFC. http://jdh.hamkins.org/km-implies-conzfc/

Comment: @Not Mike that was very very good.

Comment: @Sushil And by way of the soundness theorem, MK proves the usual sentence "Con(ZFC)" in the language of set theory as well. Those two sentences, and many others, **really are** provably equivalent within ZFC (indeed much less).